# Authenticate with Twitter using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, mechanize

I'm using Mehanize and want to authenticate to a site Twitter OAuth for authentication.

```
require 'mechanize'
agent       = Mechanize.new
homepage    = agent.get(HOME_URL)
auth        = homepage.link_with(href: AUTH_URL)
form        = auth.form_with(action: AUTH_ACTION)
uname       = form.fields[2]
pword       = form.fields[3]
uname.value = 'uname'
pword.value = 'pword'
loggedin    = agent.submit(form, form.buttons.first)
```

The result is a 403 exception: `echanize::ResponseCodeError: 403 => Net::HTTPForbidden for https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize -- unhandled response`

I found and tried [this article](http://stuff-things.net/2010/08/13/handling-403-forbidden-login-pages-with-ruby-mechanize/) which shows how to handle the exception but no luck in logging in.

Any insight in how I might get this to work?